# How to Prevent Database Cleaning cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, erase, database-cleaner

This is my env.rb
require 'cucumber/rails'
ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false

After running cucumber Its cleaning data from database. How to prevent data erasing

Comment: Did you look in the after hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You want cucumber scenarios to run with some sort of database cleaning otherwise every scenario becomes dependent on previously run scenarios, and you scenarios will start to fail in all sorts of strange ways that are very hard to debug.

If you are writing scenarios that are dependent on previous scenarios, you should stop that right now. If you are trying to pre-populate data for a test, try doing this in a Given, e.g.

```
Given the database is pre-populated
```

If that is too slow you have a couple of choices

1. Improve how you prepoulate the data, e.g. load a SQL dump of a saved database
2. Write scenarios that a less dependent on pre-populated data
3. Write fewer scenarios that are dependent on pre-populated data (perhaps you can unit test lower level components).

Its a fundamental part of all automated testing, that you start each test/scenario from a stable, constistent, repeatable starting point.